# compass removes css comments in compiled css

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, prepros

i really need having my comments compiled in the final css file of my compass project, but all my comments are deleted while compiling.

i tried setting `line_comments = true` in the `config.rb` file and i get the line comments, but not my own comments.

how can i solve this?

i'm using liferay cms, and the outdated version of our css minifier doesn't minify mediaqueries the right way so in production, all my mediaqueries won't work unless i write this little comment:

```
@media all and /*!YUI compressor*/ (max-width: 480px) {}
```

is there a way to tell compass not to delete my own comments?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include your sass/compass code. Are you using loud comments? They should be in css. Maybe wrap what you need in mixin and then @include mixin instead of what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compass basically uses the SASS settings for comments and output style which are [documented here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments)

Basically, it should leave in your block comments, but need to make sure you're not using the `compressed` output style, otherwise everything will be removed anyway.

If you're not using `compressed` and your block comments are still being removed, it might be because they're still declared in-line (I'm not sure what behaviour compass has in that regard). Try moving them to the line before like this:

```
/*!YUI compressor*/
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

The `line_comments` option just outputs comments before each selector saying where that rule is defined in your SCSS file (as long as your not using `compressed`) , it was useful before compass supported source-maps

Comment: unfortunately the css minifier needs the comment to be on a single line and exactly there. but thanks for the advices on how compass handles comments, i didn't know it kept the multilines ones.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my way of removing comments from compiled CSS is:

Use `//` to all the comments you don't want to be shown after compilation

Use `/* */` normal CSS comments for comments you want to see in your compiled CSS.

For example, You don't want to show the comments of Grid mixins just add `//` before the normal css comments

`///*=============== Grid Mixins =================*/`

Answer (score 0):

Updating to last Sass version fixes the issue. Now it keeps loud comments in compressed output files. Be sure that you have the at least Sass 3.4.22 with this command:

```
sass -v
```